# Open Mat-Select Drop down in Angular when focus comes on Mat-Select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to open Mat-Select Drop down when I press Tab key if coming from previous field or Shift + Tab if coming from the next field after Drop Down. How to achieve this ?

[image: This is my Account Page]

Now, as in the image - Account Type is my Mat-Select Drop Down. So if I press tab key from Account Name focus will shift to Account Type but I want to open the Drop Down. Like Wise if I Press Shift + Tab key combination from Company I want to open Drop - Down of Account Type.

I went through all the [Angular Material Select API's](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) but not able to achieve my goal.

This is my Account Type Drop Down Code -

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-label-line-height">
        <mat-label>Account Type </mat-label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="AccountTypeCode" [disabled]="this.DataService.LeaseCount" [(ngModel)]="AccountModel.AccountTypeCode">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let AccountType of this.AccountTypeList" [value]="AccountType.Code">
                {{ AccountType.Name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('AccountTypeCode', 'required')">Account Type is required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('CompanyCode', 'min')">Account Type is required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far, I have tried -

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-label-line-height">
        <mat-label>Account Type </mat-label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select (open)="matSelectOpen($event)" formControlName="AccountTypeCode" [disabled]="this.DataService.LeaseCount" [(ngModel)]="AccountModel.AccountTypeCode">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let AccountType of this.AccountTypeList" [value]="AccountType.Code">
                {{ AccountType.Name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('AccountTypeCode', 'required')">Account Type is required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('CompanyCode', 'min')">Account Type is required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

In .ts File -

```
matSelectOpen(e) {
    Console.log(e); //just to check whether function is called or not
}
```

I have also tried with event as follows : -

> (trigger)="matSelectOpen($event)"
>
> (panelOpen)="matSelectOpen($event)"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
 <mat-select #accType (focus)="accType.open()">
```

Which means give your select a template ref. Then on focus open it.

**Edit :**

It's been a while since I answer this and didn't notice the comment that @KrunalShah made.

If you want a general solution that can be applied to multiple selects, you are right it's not feasible to give `templateRef` to each select element. Here you can do is to create an `angular directive` to serve this purpose:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "mat-select[appOpenOnFocus]"
})
export class OpenOnFocusDirective {
  constructor(select: MatSelect) {
    const nativeEl = select._elementRef.nativeElement;
    nativeEl.addEventListener("focus", () => {
      select.open();
    });
  }
}
```

Then use it on the `mat-select` like this : `<mat-select appOpenOnFocus>`

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-zpn4ai-open-on-focus?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Can i achieve this without passing Id ?

Comment: its not an id its a template ref and what's bad about using a ref? what you want to achieve? a more dynamic solution?

Comment: I have used a lot of Mat-Select Drop downs in my project. So if i want to achieve this using Ref i have to pass Template to each dropdowns. So i am thinking of achieving it using common code or common function to achieve my functionality. Thanks

Comment: @KrunalShah I know it's been a while but didn't notice your comment before. Check the updated answer.

Comment: After upgrading to Angular 15+, it seems clicking mat-select will also trigger "focus" event, causing the dropdown menu to fluctuate.

Comment: @Roy.L.T I can't observe that fluctuation. See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pvsz9u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmat-select-focus.directive.ts) made with Angular 17

Comment: @Eldar check this out. [StackBlitz Angular v17](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pvsz9u-zksugu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmat-select-focus.directive.ts). Click the input first then click the Mat-Select. Try a few times and you should see the dropdown fluctuates.
   
As comparison, check this on version 15, [StackBlitz Angular v15](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7tmynx?file=src%2Fselect-open-on-focus.directive.ts), there's no fluctuation.
   
My guess is, in Angular v17, clicking Mat-Select will trigger "focus" event, so `select.open` is called twice, which causes the fluctuation.

Comment: @Roy.L.T calling open twice won't open the select as it checks if it is already opened. It should lose focus and regain to fluctuate. I will look into your sample when i have tim

Comment: Hi @Eldar , just to let you know that I've created an issue on Angular GitHub [#28280](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/28280), which has been confirmed and fixed in [#28287](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/28287) after one day. What a prompt action!

Comment: @Roy.L.T Nice to hear that, as I understand it opens before the option items are rendered properly and it enlarges to the full size when it is fully rendered. It is noticeable when a large number of items are contained. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

try this：

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-select (focus)="openedChange()">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let rcvFile of rcvFileList" [value]="rcvFile.src" placeholder="选择">
           
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for *mat-select* based on related event. If the option is selected, the drop-down list will not be displayed again.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelectOpenOnFocus]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class SelectOpenOnFocusDirective {
  constructor(@Self() private select: MatSelect) {}

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
  onFocus(event: FocusEvent): void {
    const eventTarget = event.relatedTarget as HTMLInputElement;
    if (eventTarget?.nodeName != 'MAT-OPTION') {
      this.select.open();
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-select appSelectOpenOnFocus>
```

**Demo Example: Look at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yz7jwa?file=src%2Fmain.ts)**